How to compare a file on a local Git branch with its equivalent on a remote branch
I have found a number of posts which show how one can perform a diff between a local and a remote branch. However, I would like to do that for just a single file.
I was using the answers given in [how-to-compare-a-local-git-branch-with-its-remote-branch1 as a starting point, but I get fatal: bad revision  when I do the following:
git diff <local path filename>  -- <remote path>filename

git diff -- <local path filename>  <remote path>filename or git diff <branch/tag/commit> -- <local path filename>  <remote path>filename

For your use-case, the mental model is not "I want to compare two files on two commits", but rather "I want to compare two commits and restrict the comparison to one file".

Appreciate that the functional equivalents of remote branches on your local Git setup are the remote tracking branches.  You may try something along the lines of the following:
git diff master origin/master -- path/to/somefile.txt

Note that if your remote master branch could have new changes, then you should first do a git fetch before attempting the above.  Also, you can use the above on any Git branch by replacing master with the other branch name.
